# Help needed with URL Parsing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url

Hi I am trying to parse a url that contains symbol(|) in it but doing

```
URI.parse .....access_token=106573539424936|2558f0741b0f2c304b70f1fe-586083691|ThxqKRhUrolOusMxC1COh7Wf3CM....
```

gives error because of the pipe sign. If i remove it the url is parsed successfully. How can I avoid such situation.

I tried to escape this sign but result was same. Please help me with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to escape all the string with:

```
CGI::escape(url_to_escape)
```

Answer (score 2):

if you're using URI module you will be better off with URI.encode method:

```
URI.parse(URI.encode("http://some.domain/path?access_token=a|b"))
```